# BMW F700GS has to be pushed for starting

Tags: motorcycle

My F700GS does (often) not start if I don't push it beforehand with a speed on. 20cm is enough.
When starting my F700GS, I only hear "click" as if the battery was flat. It does not start.
Pushing it on 20cm (8 inches) with a speed on is enough to "unlock" it. The next pressure on the button starts the motor normally.
The accu is fully loaded.
Something like decompression not occurring?

Comment: Check the battery connections. The starter may not be getting enough juice to get over the spot where the engine stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Check the magnetic starter, magnetic starter is the one that converts from the switch to the starter motor.

My Megelli 250 always had that problem, the accu is full, but it cannot start the bike. I changed the magnetic starter, and ta-da...